# Regex Multiple Expressions Getting Duplicates C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, list, csv

I am using a string list in c#, which contains a list of subjects.

E.g art, science, music.

I then have the user input "I would like to study science and art."

I would like to store the results into a variable, but I get lots of duplicates like "science, sciencemusic" (that's not a typo).

I think it's from the looping of the for each statement. Could there be an easier way to do this or is there something wrong in my code? I can't figure it out.

Here's my code:

```
string input = "I would like to study science and art.";
string result = "";

foreach (string sub in SubjectsClass.SubjectsList)
{
    Regex rx = new Regex(sub, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(input);

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        result += match.Value;
    }
}
```

The subjects class function "SubjectsList" is read from a CSV file with only words in it of random subjects:

CSV File:

Computing
English
Maths
Art
Science
Engineering

```
private list<string> subjects = new list<string>();

//Read data from csv file to list...

public list<string>SubjectsList
{
   get { return subjects; }
{
```

Currently the output I get is this:

```
"input": "art science",
"Subject": "artscienceartscienceartscience"
```

If I change:

```
result += match.Value;
```

to

```
result += match.Value + " ";
```

I get lots of spaces.

edit: I should mention that this code runs on a WPF c# button press and then shows the result.

Comment: Do this result += match.Value + " "'; only when match.Success, like: if (match.Success) { result += match.Value + " "; }

Comment: Your code is kind of incomplete, it's hard to reproduce the behavior, or to track the issue. But I'd probably check your loops - it looks like it is passing several times for the same place. You probably also should look into your expression - it might be creating incorrect matches (more than you are expecting)...

Comment: Why don't you just do a `if(input.Contains(sub)) result+=sub;` inside your loop?

Comment: I just ran your code on the input `"art science"` and got the result `"artscience"`, not `"artscienceartscienceartscience"` as you say in the question. Can you please make sure that you provide enough code so that I can copy/paste/run your code and get the result you're getting. We need a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, and with the following test data:

```
List<string> subjects = new List<string>{"Science", "Art", "Maths"};
string input = "I would like to study science and art.";
```

I don't get duplicates.

To avoid blank matches, perform a check on the value being empty

```
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Value))
       {
            result += match.Value + " ";
       }
}
```

Comment: I've just tried your suggestion, and get the input "computing" with result "computing computing".

Comment: As other commenters have stated, that isn't what the code you have posted does. Is your declaration of the result string separate from the code that performs the loop such that this is called multiple times without resetting the result value to empty, or does a subject appear more than once in the SubjectsClass.SubjectsList collection?